# Appendchild is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to create a child node for a div tag using the AppendChild method (doing it for twitter tweet text box). But it is appending only the text content and skipping all the other fields of the html tag (like class, id etc.. ) What would be the problem?

This is the code snippet i have used..

```
var elt = document.getElementById("tweet-box-home-timeline");
element = document.createElement("li");
var t = document.createTextNode('hello world');
element.appendChild(t);
element.setAttribute("class","testClass");
elt.appendChild(element)
```

but the result looks almost like this

```
<div aria-labelledby="tweet-box-home-timeline-label" name="tweet" id="tweet-box-home-timeline" class="tweet-box rich-editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" data-placeholder-default="What's happening?" data-placeholder-poll-composer-on="Ask a question..." dir="ltr" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-dropdown-4">
     <div>hello world</div>
```

Comment: You're not able to see `li`?? I could see the same with attributes.

Comment: Why are you trying to append a list item to a div? That's forbidden in HTML. List items are only allowed as children of unordered and ordered lists.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/babeyo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The problem is that twitter is validating the innerhtml and removing all the tags and just keeping the text content.. Any idea for overriding this?